# function is not able to find the time between start_time and end_time when end value is less than start

Tags: javascript, node.js

My function is as shown below:

```
function inTime(startTime, endTime) {
    function toMins(v) {
        v = v.split(':');
        return v[0] * 60 + +v[1];
    }

    const nowTime = new Date();
    startTime = new Date(+nowTime).setHours(0, toMins(startTime), 0, 0);
    endTime = new Date(+nowTime).setHours(0, toMins(endTime), 0, 0);
    return nowTime >= startTime && nowTime <= endTime;
}
```

This function works perfectly when `startTime` value is less than `endTime`. But suppose if my `startTime` is `18:30` and my `endTime` is `3:30` and `nowTime` is `2:30` then it is not able to identify that `nowTime` is between `startTime` and `endTime`. So how should I modify this function so that it can cover this testcase?

Comment: @Barmar I have update my code.

Comment: If `endTime` is less than `startTime`, add 1 day to `endTime`.

Comment: @Barmar can you please post it as answer?

Comment: `now` is not defined

Comment: @Vasanth please check for my updated question code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `endTime` is less than `startTime`, it must be wrapping around midnight, so add 1 day to `endTime`. And then you need to use `||` instead of `&&` to compare the current time (if you're testing between `23:00` and `02:00`, you want anything that's between `23:00` and `23:59` or between `00:00` and `02:00`).

Another problem was that you were assigning the return value of `setHours()` to the variables. This returns the time as a number; we need to keep these variables as `Dates`.

```js
function inTime(startTime, endTime) {
  function toMins(v) {
    v = v.split(':');
    return v[0] * 60 + +v[1];
  }

  const nowTime = new Date();
  var startMins = toMins(startTime);
  startTime = new Date(+nowTime);
  startTime.setHours(0, startMins, 0, 0);
  var endMins = toMins(endTime)
  endTime = new Date(+nowTime);
  endTime.setHours(0, endMins, 0, 0);
  if (endTime < startTime) {
    endTime.setDate(endTime.getDate() + 1);
    return nowTime > startTime || nowTime < endTime;
  } else {
    return nowTime >= startTime && nowTime <= endTime;
  }
}

console.log(inTime('23:00', '02:00'))
```

Comment: I tried your code. It gives me error `endTime.getDate()` is not function

Comment: I've fixed it. You need to keep the variables as `Date` instead of converting to integers.

Answer (score 1):

You might want end OR start time adjustment

```
....
if (startTime > endTime) {
  if (endTime < now) {
      endTime.setTime(endTime.getTime() + 86400000);
  } else {
    startTime.setTime(startTime.getTime() - 86400000);
  }
}
return now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
```

But, as shifting a time by one day warrants a respective condition satisfaction, you may do it in a simplier way:

```
if (startTime > endTime) {
  if (endTime < now) {
      return now >= startTime;
      //Example: start: 1:30, now:18:30, end: 0:30 -> true
      //Example: start: 20:30, now:18:30, end: 0:30 -> false
  } else {
      return now <= endTime;
      //Example: start: 21:30, now:1:30, end: 20:30 -> true
      //Example: start: 21:30, now:21:00, end: 20:30 -> false
  }
}
return now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
```

Then, we observe that `now <= endTime` under two `if`s trivially follows `startTime > endTime` AND `endTime => now` conditions of enclosing `if` operators so we may evaluate it to **true** obtaining the following.

```
if (startTime > endTime) {
      return (now <= endTime || now >= startTime);
}
return now >= startTime && now <= endTime;
```

It seems `startTime > endTime` merely changes `&&` into `||` in the start+end time condition combination :-)